# Redirecting from getInitialProps in _error.js in nextjs?

Tags: next.js

Any way to redirect to another url from getInitialProps in **_error.js** in nextjs?

Already tried   **res.redirect('/');** inside getInitialProps.

Its giving
*TypeError: res.redirect is not a function*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although, this redirect from `_error.js` doesn't feel right to me, you can try something like below:

```
import Router from 'next/router'

// in your getInitialProps
if (res) { // server
  res.writeHead(302, {
    Location: '/'
  });

  res.end();
} else { // client
  Router.push('/');
}
```

Since `getInitialProps` might be executed on the client when navigating to a different route, you should also consider adding the else case.

Also, I would suggest you to rethink your approach. `_error.js` is used to handle 404 and 500 errors and you shouldn't need a redirect at this level.

---

In case you are importing the [Error component](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#reusing-the-built-in-error-page), `getInitialProps` of `_error.js` will not be triggered.

Comment: For those who are having issues with the page hanging, don't forget to include the `res.end()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```js
YourPage.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  ctx.res.writeHead(302, {
    Location: '/some_url',
    'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
  });
  ctx.res.end();
     
  return {};
};
```